# candle creation on a monthly basis using the scores in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a candle using the table as below. It has a score and month and there can be as many as 4 scores in a month.

```
id | score | month
1  |   10  | 12
.. |   ..  |  ..
```

And here is what I actually did,

```
select 
   score as open, 
   max(score) as high, 
   min(score) as low 
from score_table 
group by month
```

I am successful in getting Open, high and low.
My problem is getting the close, basically the fourth score of a month. I tried some solutions using joins unfortunately I am wrong and couldn't get it right which actually landed me in too many confusion. I'm not good at SQL and need help...

Comment: What's a candle?

Answer (score 0):

I see when you group by month the records just give you a high and a low with the same values

What I changed is to get the month and the high and low . 
There should be separate columns for the high ,low and open in a list form to break the high lows up per time period (if you only working on one candle its fine but many candles over a time period there should be a row for each time period)

that data is quite hard to work with the way the table is set out but you can construct something like this to make it easier for your self

---

### id  | Month | Open | High | Low |

would be more ideal to work with that data but non the the least I changed the the MySQL query a bit to reflect data as per your description. I achieved it by combining 2 MySQL queries to get the open data from row 3

```
select x.open, y.high, y.low from ( select (score)  as open
from score 
where id = 3 )as x,

(select  max(score) as high,
min(score) as low 
from score ) as y;
```